# Django URL mapping for different apps

Tags: html, django

Im trying to link a button in HTML to another html in my project folder for my django project. Lets say its

```
MyApp

-Polls
   -templates
      -index
-Votes
   -templates
      -main
      -truths
      -rigged
```

I have a a button on main that uses rigged and truths so in main it has this button

```
<form action="{% url 'Votes:rigged' %}">
    <input type="submit" value="rigged votes" />
</form>
```

now i want to add another button that would link polls->index into it. Is there a way to do that without copying everything from Polls into the folder Votes?

UPDATE*
main.html

```
<form action="{% url 'Polls:Index' %}">
    <input type="submit" value="Index" />
</form>
```

Polls.url

```
urlpatterns=[    
    url(r'^Index/', Index.as_view(), name="Index"),
]
```

Index.views

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    # template location
    template_name = "Polls/Index.html"

    # post logic must be defined
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return redirect(reverse_lazy("Polls:Index"))
```

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question but if you just want to use the html from index you can break the repetitive part of the html in a snippet and then include it like `{% include 'index' %} 
or if you are trying to use the link of the form in index you can take the same approach as you did for 'rigged votes'. Just use the form url in action

Comment: @AdityaPandhare so I have 2 different apps within my project (polls and votes) each has their own page like django/main, django/truths, django/rigged, and django/index. I want to create a button that is placed into django/main and when the button is clicked it redirects to django/index.

Comment: Just replace the action address with "{% url 'Polls:index' }%". What is nagging you? I assume you know how namespace urls work.

Comment: @AdityaPandhare I get an error noreversematch at main. Polls is not a registered namespace

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces
Please understand how the namespaces and named urls work. You should have a urls.py file in your 'MyApp' folder where other files like 'settings.py' and 'wigs.py' are there.
For referring to an url by namespaces you need to first register the namespace associated with url.py of your Polls app. Example from the documentation:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='Polls')),
]
```

Furthermore you must also name your url in 'polls.urls' like

```
url(r'^index/$', Whatever_view,name='index'),
```

then you can call the url as "Polls:index"

Comment: Can you share the code in urls.py and html code too? or if you use debug toolbar you can share the debug file from there?

Comment: still don't see a namespace named 'Polls' being defined here. Also, you are also supposed to define a method for the form.